# git svn clone fatal error

Tags: git, svn, git-clone, svn2git

I'm trying to migrate svn repository to git. I'm getting the following error:

> fatal: .git\svn\refs\remotes\https;C:\Program Files\Git\index: index file open failed: Invalid argument
>
> (in cleanup) update-index -z --index-info: command returned error: 128

I looked in the path and couldn't find any index file. Any help how to solve this error will be really helpful.

Comment: Do you use git-svn as a frontend for an eixisting SVN repository that remains exisiting or do you try to do a one-time conversion of an SVN repository to Git?

Comment: one time conversion of an the svn repository to Git

Comment: I had the same problem but then I used https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git and that worked for me.

Comment: Can you provide the solution if you've solved the issues?

Answer (score 0):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is great if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for a one-time conversion you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to configure it for your layout to get the result you want and expect.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.